# Loading multiple shapefiles using shp2pgsql in a bash script

Tags: postgis

I have this bash script (loadShapefiles.sh) to load multiple shapefiles at a time. The script and the shapefiles are stored in the same directory. When I run the bash file with the command of `bash loadShapefiles.sh`, I have this error message: `syntax error near unexpected token '$'do\r''` .

```
for f in *.shp
do
    shp2pgsql -d -I -s 2913 $f rlis.`basename $f .shp` > `basename $f .shp`.sql  
done    

for f in *.sql  
do  
    psql -d portland -f $f  
done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are missing some semicolons. Bash uses different syntax to Python.

In bash and similar shell syntax, one alternative would be:

```
for f in *.shp; do shp2pgsql -d -I -s 2913 $f rlis.`basename $f.shp` > `basename $f.shp`.sql; done
for f in *.sql; do psql -d portland -f $f; done
```